# Do private event handlers break encapsulation?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, encapsulation

Everybody knows that private event handler can listen to an event from other class. (Examples in documentation always use just private handlers.)

Event handler is nothing more than a private method in another class than the calling event. So calling the handler from outside its class breaks encapsulation. Or am I missing something?

Example code, for completeness:

```
 class Caller    {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
       MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    private void MyPrivateHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a private method!");
    }

    public void Subscribe(Caller caller)
    {
        caller.MyEvent += this.MyPrivateHandler;
    }
}
```

and after subscription `receiver.Subscribe(caller);`  we can comfortably call private method in `receiver` class from outside: `caller.RaiseMyEvent();`.

It is a purely academic question, even scholastic. Moreover, I personally find this feature very convenient, practical, and actually love it. It is really cool: we can explicitly grant other classes the right to call our private methods. (We can also unsibscribe it and make a lot of fascinating stuff with delegates and events.) Anyway, it still violates the purity of encapsulation... or not?

P.S.: Thanks to Matthew Watson for pointing the following nuance: when subscribed to event, private handler can be called exclusively by this event. While if we make it public (or call via public wrapper method), it can be called by anybody. It's quite a difference in accessibility.

P.P.S: And yes - I've never seen this issue mentioned in a textbook. If you know one, please leave a reference.

Comment: It doesn't break encapsulation any more than calling a public method which goes on to call a private method, IMO.

Comment: Matthew Watson: Not exactly in the same way. If we call private handler from public method (within the same class, of course), then anybody can call this public method, and, therefore, the handler. While when subscribed to event, the private handler can be called exclusively by this event.

Comment: Yes, but only because the class with the private method is doing so. This is an implementation detail which is NOT observable from outside the `Receiver` class. There is no way for another class to directly call `MyPrivateHandler` (other than by using reflection, of course).

Comment: Absolutely. By the way, it answers the question "How to call private method from outside the class", although in a special way. And again,  formal privateness has a hole in it. Very useful and genuinely designed for explicitly declared Mickey Mouse, it's still a hole :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, when you do caller.RaiseMyEvent() from outside of either class, you don't have to have a clue who's going to handle the event.

In fact, I don't think the Subscribe-method in the Receiver should be public, this kind of defeats the purpose. If the Receiver is interested in handling the event, it should subscribe itself, it shouldn't let others subscribe it. This way you keep the subscription-status and the method that deals with it hidden.

There is no direct calling of this private method in the Receiver-class and you shouldn't assume anything about it. The receiver-class at any point could unsubscribe itself.

It fiddles with encapsulation, but I don't think it violates it entirely. It's basically a broadcast system.

If some television station advises people to go out and steal an apple and they actually do it, who is to blame? The TV station or the people who steal? I would think the latter.
The same is true about events, the one who raises the event shouldn't have to worry about the implications.

Comment: Maybe my examle was misleading a bit. It is not important, who raises the event - normally it is sonething within the class containing the event. Similarly, subscription policy is controlled within class containing handler. The issue is that normally private method can be called from outside the class. After all, event handlers are nothing but methods - and private methods are supposed to be called privately, aren't they?

Comment: I understand your point, but you're also not really calling a private method from some place else, you're raising an event which calls a private method. The method itself is still called privately because the subscription is done privately. You can't force a class to call its private method by raising the event. It's only an after-effect.

Comment: Disagree with: _"The method itself is still called privately because the subscription is done privately."_ The flow of execution goes from raising event to the subscribed private handler. Private status of subscription is very important, but we subscribe only once - and then calls flow smoothly to the (not so very private) method.

Comment: But if you raise the event 100 times in a row, you can never be sure that the private method is being called 100 times. It can unsubscribe itself in the event handler and the method is never going to be called again. So this flow is not as direct as you might think. And this is how it differs from calling methods through their objects: object.DoMethod() called 100 times will (barring exceptions etc) execute 100 times.

Comment: Yes. Anyway the private method (maybe temporarily) becomes callable from outside the class. So it is neither strictly private, nor public (or protected  etc.) Actually it falls out of strict encapsulation scheme.

Comment: I agree with that, it falls out of the encapsulation scheme. It's even worse when working with an event "bus", like Unity/Prism's EventAggregator. This basically means that you can send events from one end of your application all the way to the other end, spaghetti code yay!

Answer (score 0):

the private event handler is private because you are only intrested to provide the user an option to use it as an event.

```
private void MyPrivateHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm a private method!");
}

public void Subscribe(Caller caller)
{
    caller.MyEvent += this.MyPrivateHandler;
}
```

is same as

```
public void Subscribe(Caller caller)
{
    caller.MyEvent += (sender,e)=>{Console.WriteLine("I'm a anonymous method!"); }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not the same. Event handler is just a method. It is private for encapsulation, not because it is supposed to handle some event. Maybe I want to call it from `Receiver` class for some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit off topic, it's related to your question and you might find it interesting: [a link to a blog post about customizing the adding and removing of C# event handlers](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/25/intercepting-add-and-remove-of-c-event-delegates/). The comments are worth reading. One relevant comment references this [answer ("Event Acessors" by Stephen Toub)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/magazine/cc163533%28en-us%29.aspx), from MSDN Magazine, to the blog post question.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I actually only looked through it (sorry), so cannot judge in details.